# Javascript getting the number of elements in getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
b = document.getElementsByClassName('name1');
c = document.getElementsByClassName('name2');
if (b.length != 0) {
    document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = b[0].innerHTML 
else if (c.length != 0) {
    document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = c[0].innerHTML
}
else document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'error';
```

But I am not getting the desired rendering. The whole page renders even when divs with class name name1 and name2 are present.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least you skipped the closing `}` bracket in `if` statement. Then, there is no `getElementByTagName` method in native JavaScript.

Comment: And it's getElementsByTagName (plural Elements)

Comment: @SegFault are there multiple divs in your page with class `name1 ` or `name2`?

Comment: This code has several syntax errors.

Comment: @rahulmaindargi, no only single elements with those class names

Comment: @SegFault see the answer by VisioN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You skipped the closing `}` bracket in `if` statement;
2. There is no `getElementByTagName` method in native JavaScript;
3. You'd better use `document.body` instead.

Here is a bit more correct code:

```
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("name1"),
    c = document.getElementsByClassName("name2");

if (b.length > 0) {
    document.body.innerHTML = b[0].innerHTML;
} else if (c.length > 0) {
    document.body.innerHTML = c[0].innerHTML;
} else {
    document.body.innerHTML = "error";
}
```

Also, I wouldn't suggest you to change `.innerHTML` property, it is much efficient to use `.appendChild()` method instead, i.e.:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("error"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You were using getElementByTagName instead of getElementsByTagName. Here is the updated script.

```
b = document.getElementsByClassName('name1');
c = document.getElementsByClassName('name2');
if (b.length != 0) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = b[0].innerHTML;
else if (c.length != 0) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = c[0].innerHTML;
    }
    else document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'error';
}
```